# git rebase overwrites the files from current branch

Tags: git, git-rebase

git rebase overwrites the files from our branch with the develop branch.

When we did `git rebase develop` we were on our branch `fix_parser` as we wanted to rebase it with develop.

We had our changes already commited and pushed too.

Now the rebase tries to modify commited files. As xyx_parser had Flake8 done yet rebase took the file from develop and ran Flake8 on it and complained about Flake8 where as our file was done formatting.

Please explain behind the scenes as this is happening due to lack of our knowledge.

We tried `git rebase develop` and expected it to revert the changes that we did not made.

Comment: `git rebase`  is the process of moving or combining a sequence of commits to a new base commit. In your case if the `develop` branch has modified the files, with rebase the modification will then exist in you branch after rebase.

Comment: Can you expand on your last sentence? I think that may be where the confusion is, because rebase wouldn't normally be described as "reverting" anything.

Answer (score 0):

`rebase` takes a range of commits and "copies" them to a new base. The defaultu mode of operation is to `pick` commits, which is very similar in idea to how `git cherry-pick` works.

Simplified, the steps could be described as:

```
git format-patch old-base..branch-to-rebase
git checkout new-base
git apply-patch *patches-from-above*
```

Nothing is reverted, but of course, changes of your branch and the new base will both be visible. The resulting `tree` is not that much different from running `git merge`.

Here's a visual example:

```
* ccccccc  add file 'c' (branch)
| * bbbbbbb  add file 'b' (new-base)
|/
* aaaaaaa  initialize with file 'a' (old-base)
```

Now running `git rebase --onto new-base old-base branch` (or the equivalent `git checkout branch; git rebase new-base`) will produce the following rewritten history:

```
* c2c2c2c  add file 'c' (branch)
* bbbbbbb  add file 'b' (new-base)
* aaaaaaa  initialize with file 'a' (old-base)
```

It should be obvious that commit `c2c2c2c` (the rewritten/copied version of `ccccccc`) now contains files a, b, and c; while the original `ccccccc` only contained files a and c.